# How to get all data of table and apply if condition dynamodb

Tags: jquery, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am looking into this documentation  `http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html`

there is `get_item`  function to get a specific element but I want to get all data of this table . Is there any way to get all table data ? And there is no way mention to get data on basis of `If` condition as well  ?

P.S I am new in dynamodb any help would be highly appreciated . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation that you need is the scan operation.

As per the name, the operation Scans the entire table and return the results in chunks of 1MB. In this situation it also returns a LastEvaluatedKey info. That info permits you to start a new scan from this point on to get another 1MB...

Just keep in mind that this operation has a high cost in terms of performance and read troughput!

Comment: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.scan